# How to play sounds on button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to play a sound based on a randomly generated color in a list. The list name is gamePattern always contain a colour. At first I hear sound but subsequently I wont hear. Please what is wrong with my code?

```
function makeSound (num){
    if (num[0] === "blue"){
        var blue = new Audio("sounds/blue.mp3");
        blue.play();
        console.log(num[0])
    }else if (num[0] === "green"){
        var green = new Audio("sounds/green.mp3");
        green.play();
        console.log(num[0])
    }else if (num[0] === "red"){
        var red = new Audio("sounds/red.mp3");
        red.play();
        console.log(num[0])
    }else if (num[0] === "wrong"){
        var wrong = new Audio("sounds/wrong.mp3");
        wrong.play();
        console.log(num[0])
    }else if (num[0] === "yellow"){
        var yellow = new Audio("sounds/yellow.mp3");
        yellow.play();
        console.log(num[0])
    }

}
console.log(gamePattern[0])
makeSound(gamePattern)
```

I added the console.log to be sure the conditions are always the same. Yet the sound does not play. The path to the sound is also correct

Comment: DId you turn on your speakers? :D 
Can you share the output of the console.log with us? Just to be save.

Comment: I don't know how large your files are, but did you take a look at [Determining when playback can begin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio#determining_when_playback_can_begin)?

Comment: Consider adding the audio elements to the HTML, then something like `document.getElementById("BlueAudio").play()`

Comment: Could you post all of the code including the button interaction? Your code works fine for me when calling the function from a button onclick event, tested on multiple browsers.